# storing ssh results in variable fails

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

following works:

```
$ ssh $host crontab -l| grep myjob
```

but if I want to store it in a variable it grabs everything in the current folder of local host with the result from remote server in the end. confused why so???

```
$ x=`ssh $host crontab -l| grep myjob`
$ echo $x
...blah ..blah... ...myjob.
```

for example below works fine:

```
x=`ssh $host pwd`
echo $x
```

(properly displays remote pwd)

Comment: Quote the variable. Otherwise all the `*` in the crontab entry are expanded as filename wildcards.

Comment: Use `echo "$x"`